# Why is my webpack build detecting so many orphan modules?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I've just updated to `webpack 5`.

This is my `webpack.config.ts`:

```
import * as path from "path";
import * as webpack from "webpack";

const config: webpack.Configuration = {

  mode: "production",

  devtool: false,

  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash:5].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.tsx"
  },

  module: {
    rules:[{
      test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      use: ["babel-loader"]
    }]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ ... })
  ],

  optimization: {
    moduleIds: "deterministic",
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          filename: `vendors.[contenthash:5].js`
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's pretty standard.

This is the bundle output:

[image]

Everything makes sense. This is what we have:

- A `runtime` chunk. From the `runtimeChunk: "single"` option
- A `vendors` chunk. From the `defaultVendors` cacheGroup
- An `app` chunk, from the `app: "./src/index.tsx"` entrypoint

But there are other logs that I don't understand:

**orphan modules**

[image]

Why is `webpack` detecting so many modules as **orphan**? My total amount of files in my `src` folder is around ~500. There are probably some lost files in there, but I'm pretty sure most of them should not be considered orphan by any means, since they are used across the app code.

This is their definition for orphan modules:

[image]

And I'm pretty sure most of my `src` files are included in the `app` chunk. So how could they be considered orphan? Can I inspect or log which modules are being considered orphan?

I'm not sure if this started on webpack 5 or not. Don't remember if webpack 4 logs also had this. Should I worry about this? It's not triggering any `warnings`, but it gets logged like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been curious about orphan modules, as I was analyzing my webpack stats. I noticed that concatenated modules are always considered orphan modules. If you look in webpack bundle analyzer and see concatenated modules, those will be your orphan modules most likely. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not in webpack.

Comment: What do you mean by concatenated modules?

Comment: Webpack automatically inlines code together as an optimization in some cases. If you use bundle analyzer plug-in you’ll see the concatenated modules in your build. - for more info on concatenation - take a look here https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/

Comment: `webpack bundle analyzer` is a useful hint, thanks!

Comment: webpack seems to consider this not a bug, though I'm not sure I understand the explanation. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12568

Answer (score -1):

Have you actually read what orphan module is? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#statsorphanmodules

Why do you think it's included. Probably it's wepback detection for something that is not used. Lib can contain many modules, but not all of them (even if you connect them) are used in your application.